# NAs in weekdays() function

Tags: r

I'm working with some dates and need to convert the actual date to a day of the week.  I'm using the `weekdays()` function and any day over 13 is producing `NA`s.

```
example<-c("1/1/2000","1/3/2000","1/13/2000","1/15/2000","2/3/2000","2/8/2000","2/29/2000")

example<-weekdays(as.Date(example))

example
#[1] "Saturday"  "Tuesday"   NA          NA          "Wednesday" "Tuesday"  
#[7] NA
```

No matter what month or year, every day under the 13th produces the correct output, but nothing over the 13th.

Comment: Look at the result of `as.Date("1/1/2000")` - you need to specify the appropriate format.

Answer (score 2):

Just specify the `format` for `as.Date`

```
example<-c("1/1/2000","1/3/2000","1/13/2000","1/15/2000","2/3/2000","2/8/2000","2/29/2000")

weekdays(as.Date(example, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
#[1] "Saturday" "Monday"   "Thursday" "Saturday" "Thursday" "Tuesday"  "Tuesday"
```

`as.Date` actually tries to guess the format; you can see the different `tryFormats` (`"%Y-%m-%d"` and `"%Y/%m/%d"`) when you take a look at `?as.Date`.

---

A care-free alternative would be to use `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
weekdays(anydate(example))
#[1] "Saturday" "Monday"   "Thursday" "Saturday" "Thursday" "Tuesday"  "Tuesday"
```

Answer (score 0):

Total guess without looking and with not near enough caffeine in the blood ... your date layout is expecting DD/MM/YYYY so anything >12 for MM is going to barf out.

I think you can specify the actual input date format but again, not enough coffee.

Answer (score 0):

I like using `lubridate` to import dates, it's easier to remember for me than the `format` parameter in `as.Date`

Here you clearly have month/day/year, to get the appropriate function in lubridate you just keep the first letters of month/day/year: mdy

```
library(lubridate)
example_dates <- mdy(example)
weekdays(example_dates)
#[1] "Saturday" "Monday"   "Thursday" "Saturday" "Thursday" "Tuesday"  "Tuesday"
```